# Sencha touch 2.0 carousel scroll on Y bouncing on IOS 7

Tags: javascript, ios, sencha-touch

This is my carousel config :

```
config: {
    id: 'carouselid',
    //style: 'background-color: #00ADEE !important;',
    baseCls: 'formPanelCls',
    ui: 'color',
    scrollable: {
        direction:'vertical',
        directionLock:true,
    },
    listeners: [
        {
            fn: 'onCarouselidActivate',
            event: 'activate'
        },
        {
            fn: 'onCarouselidPainted',
            event: 'painted'
        }
    ]
},
```

When the screen is small some of the object is cutting of at the bottom, When i try to scroll down it scrolled and bounce back up, I need to scroll down without the bouncing .
I tried to add scroll

```
{ bouncing:false}
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: I cant understand the question at all can you please explain it better?

Comment: Ya sure ... I created a carousel using Sencha touch v 2.0 , There is 3 lines of object in each line there is 3 objects. When the screen is small the object in the 3 line is cut on the bottom.When trying to scroll down to see the rest of the object there is a scroll but when you release the tap it bounce back up. So i'm unable to press the bottom objects, It occur only in IOS7